# OpenCPU with JS, functions call returns connection failed error on Android platform?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, opencpu

Has anyone used OpenCPU to call R functions using cordova on Android?

It works perfectly on a browser, I used both localhost and an external IP address.
But it logs a connection failed error when using Android. I'm using **jQuery 1.12** and **opencpu-04.js**. Any possible reasons I should check ?

Comment: Any particular error? Are you calling cross domain? A CORS issue perhaps?

Comment: It doesn't show any cors error in Chrome tho

Comment: it is cors issue solved from the server side.

Comment: The OpenCPU server sets CORS headers by default. Are you using some sort of proxy that filters them?